# From NSTextfield to (const unsigned char *) with Swift

Tags: swift, string, nstextfield, unsafe-pointers

How can i properly received a (const unsigned char *) in a C program from a NSTextField in Swift ?

**Case 1** :

```
let string1 = atextfield!.stringValue // -> "Test"
print(string1) // -> "Test"
```

string1/_core/_baseAddress = nil // in debug

```
let string2 = string1.utf8CString.withUnsafeBytes
{
    ptr -> UnsafePointer<UInt8> in
    return ptr.load(as: UnsafePointer<UInt8>.self)
}
```

fatal error: UnsafeRawBufferPointer.load out of bounds

**Case 2** :

```
let string1 = "Test"
print(string1) // -> "Test"
```

string1/_core/_baseAddress = (_rawValue = 0x... "Test") // in debug

fatal error: UnsafeRawBufferPointer.load out of bounds

**Case 3** :

```
let string1 = atextfield!.stringValue // Value = "Test"
print(string1) // -> "Test"
```

string1/_core/_baseAddress = nil // in debug

```
let string2 :UnsafePointer<UInt8> = string1.utf8CString.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
($0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: UnsafePointer<UInt8>.self, capacity: string1.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8)) {$0})}.pointee

testCPgm(string2)
```

testcfield = "" in testCPgm

```
void testCPgm(const unsigned char *testcfield)
{

}
```

**Case 4** :

```
let string1 = "Test"
print(string1) // -> "Test"
```

string1/_core/_baseAddress = (_rawValue = 0x... "Test") // in debug

testcfield = "" in testCPgm

**Case 5** --> **It Works !**

```
let string1 = "Test"

or

let string1 = atextfield!.stringValue
print(string1) // -> "Test"

testCPgm(string1) // Yes directly from String to (const unsigned char *)
```

testcfield = "Test" in testCPgm

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

This is what i found without closure.

From String (string1) to (const unsigned char *) (string2)

```
let string2 = UnsafeRawPointer(string1.cString(using: .utf8)).bindMemory(to: CUnsignedChar.self, capacity: string1.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))
```

I don't know if there is a more elegant way to do it.

i don't found the equivalent for Data (without closure) (not NSData ( use .bytes))